# Вывод числа double (10^18)+1

Tags: double, c, вывод, c++

Увидев этот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double d = 1000000000000000001;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(0); //0 - число символов после точки
    cout << d << endl;
    printf("%.0lf\n",d);
    return 0;
}
```

Неожиданно увидел в результате [(http://ideone.com/1SEHpO)](http://ideone.com/1SEHpO)

> ```
> 1000000000000000000
> 1000000000000000000
> ```

Куда делась 1?
Из за чего так происходит? Особенности записи типов с плавающей точкой?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Отображение числа 9223372036854775807](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/23044)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

У типа double ограниченная точность, поэтому в нём невозможно различить 1000000000000000000 и 1000000000000000001. Если вы объявите

```
double d1 = 1000000000000000001;
double d2 = 1000000000000000000;
```

— то `d1` и `d2` будут одним и тем же числом. Пруф: http://ideone.com/WqQSAd

Проблема в том, что числа с плавающей точкой не бесконечно точны. Для типа `double`, например, выделяется [52 бита](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) под значащие цифры (и ещё 11 бит под показатель степени), число внутри хранится как бы закодированным в виде `CCCCCCC * 2^PPPP` (`C` — значащие цифры, `P` — степень). А значит, числа, которые можно представить в виде `double`, расположены с некоторым шагом (который зависит от величины порядка): числа, расположенные «между» представимыми числами выразить точно с помощью `double` вообще нельзя, и они автоматически округляются до ближайшего представимого числа. Пример такого числа — 0.1: оно не выражается (двоичной) дробью, и константа 0.1 внутри хранится как приблизительно

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

Максимальное значение, которое можно прибавить к единице так, чтобы она не изменилась, называется [*машинным эпсилоном*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). Для типа `double` машинный эпсилон равен, очевидно, 2⁻⁵³, то есть около `1.11e-16`.

Почему очевидно? Потому что для единицы значащие биты такие: 10000000...000, а значит, следующее по величине число, которое можно выразить типом `double`, должно иметь значащие цифры 10000000...001. (На самом деле чуть-чуть сложнее: ведущая единица не хранится, а подразумевается.)

Отсюда выплывает, что `1 + 1e-16` для типа `double` неотличимо от 1. Поскольку для бóльших чисел увеличивается порядок, при увеличении первого слагаемого машинный эпсилон приблизительно пропорционально увеличивается. Соответственно, `1e16 + 1` будет равно `1e16`. В вашем же случае вы на два порядка выше предела: вы прибавляете к `1e18`.

Давайте ещё проэкспериментируем: http://ideone.com/4XJxFj

```
1 + 1.110223024625156e-16 == 1
```

но уже

```
1 + 1.110223024625157e-16 != 1
```

Это потому, что `1.110223024625156e-16` — приближение к 2⁻⁵³.

---

Ещё немного информации о числах с плавающей точкой:

- [Хорошая статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/)
- [Классическая статья с теоретическими выкладками](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), но на английском.

---

Если вам нужно представлять числа с высокой точностью, даже типа `long double` может не хватить. В этом случае, возможно, придётся применять числа *бесконечной точности*. Такие числа являются встроенными в некоторых языках (например, Java и C#), а для C и C++ есть хорошие библиотеки, предоставляющие такие числа. Я бы порекомендовал [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: @VlaD, я понимаю, но где находиться этот "предел"... Какие ограничения у этого типа?

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey: немного расширил ответ.

Comment: Лимиты вещественных чисел описаны в хидере float.h. В частности эпсилоны для различных типов называются FLT_EPSILON, DBL_EPSILON, и LDBL_EPSILON.
Аналогичный хидер для целых - limits.h

Comment: @renegator: точно! Для C++ лучше использовать темплейтный [std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)