# Золотое сечение МО

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double func(double x) // функция вызова функции
{
    return  (10*x*log10(x)/log10(2.7)-(x*x)/2); // заданная задачей функция 
}



void mZolotSech(int N, double a,double b) // сам метод
{
    long double x1,x2,y1,y2, ymin, xmin,t, er,ea; // er -> расчетная погрешность, еа->вычисляемая погрешность.
    int m,j;
    t=(1+sqrtl(5))/2; // то самое phi, отношение золотого сечения
    er=(b-a)/(2*pow(t, (N-1))); 
    x1=b-(b-a)/t;   y1=func(x1);
    x2=a+(b-a)/t;   y2=func(x2);
    m=2;
    do
    {   
        if(y1<y2)
           {b=x2;
            x2=x1; y2=y1;
            x1=b-(b-a)/t;
            y1=func(x1);
            cout<<"m="<<m<<" x1="<<x1<<" x2="<<x2<<" y1="<<y1<<" y2="<<y2<<endl;
            }
            else
            { a=x1;
            x1=x2; y1=y2;
            x2=a+(b-a)/t;
            y2=func(x2);
            cout<<"m="<<m<<" x1="<<x1<<" x2="<<x2<<" y1="<<y1<<" y2="<<y2<<endl;
            }
            m++;
    }
    while(m<N);
        if(y1<y2) b=x2;
        else a=x1;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<a<<b;
            xmin=(a+b)/2.0; ymin=func(xmin); ea=(b-a)/2.0;
            cout<<endl;
    cout<<setw(15)<<xmin<<setw(15)<<ymin<<setw(15)<<er<<setw(15)<<ea<<endl;

    _getch();
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout<<"Добро Пожаловать в программу\n";
    int N; double a,b;
    cout<<"Введите количество экспериментов=";cin>>N;cout<<"\nВведите a=";cin>>a;cout<<"\nВведите b=";cin>>b;
    mZolotSech(N,a,b); 

}
```

Вот скриншот выполнения программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим 5 строк каждая соответствует: 10,20,30,40,50 итераций.
Последние 2 строки отличаются, значительно чего не должно быть.

[Описание принципа метода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9E.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B0) (только при заданном Е *(погрешность)*)

**Мой случай:** `10х*ln(x)-x*x/2`
ограничения: [0.1;1]
Задано количество итерация(подсчетов), нужно найти Хmin, Ymin, Ер, Ев.
Ер-расчетная погрешность, Ев-вычислительная.

Comment: @Adrug игра в Угадайку продолжается? А в "золотом сечении МО" МО -- это министерство обороны?

Comment: Отредактировал, постарался более глубже передать свою проблему. 
Мне была поставлена задача: имеющуюся функцию(с границами a,b) пропустить через метод золотого сечения.

Comment: Методы оптимизации.

Comment: Ок, про бред своему преподавателю расскажешь ;-)

Comment: @Adrug попробуйте считать добавляемые точки (x1 или x2) более традиционным способом (1) Замените sqrtf на sqrt или sqrtl -- зачем там float (2) Ну и исправьте void main на int main

Comment: @Adrug, вот опубликовали ссылку и стало понятно о чем речь. А в следующий раз излагайте суть задачи сразу (и лучше своими словами, не напрягайте никого лазаньем по ссылкам).

Вы просто неправильно запрограммировали  шаг 2 алгоритма по Вашей ссылке. Там же на каждой итерации надо пересчитывать x1 и x2 по скорректированным a и b.

Посмотрите еще раз внимательно на  алгоритм и Вашу программу (код в цикле do { ... } while();)

Comment: Долго думал на этим куском программы, так и не увидел расхождений. 
Я обновляю a и b, в конструкции If после каждого прохода цикла. 
@alexlz ваш совет 1) нормализовал Ер и Еа при итераций = 30, но к сожалению 40 и 50 итераций также расходятся.

Comment: @avp, может вас смутило, что алгоритм для заданной точности, а мне необходимо найти эту самую точность при заданных итераций.

Comment: @Adrug Откорректируйте код в вопросе и приведите исходные данные.

Comment: @Adrug, смотрите , алгоритм по Вашей ссылке

     for(;;) {
       x1 = b-(b-a)/phi; x2 = a+(b-a)/phi;
       y1 = func(x1);    y2 = func(x2);
       if (y1 >= y2)
          a = x1;
       else
          b = x2;
       if (abs(b - a) < eps) {
          x = (a + b) / 2;
          break;
       }
     }

где `phi` это пресловутое *золотое сечение* == 1.618... (с `eps`, надеюсь, все понятно).

А у Вас какой-то совсем не тот алгоритм. Может он и правильный, но причем здесь тогда эта [ссылка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_золотого_сечения)?

Comment: @avp, алгоритм в приведенной ссылке считает количество итераций при заданном Ев(вычислительная погрешность), мне необходимо же найти эту погрешность уже при заданных итераций. 
@alexlz, привел в код в текущее состояние. 
Спасибо за понимание. Жду вашей помощи. 
Расчет был на то что на данном сервисе найдутся люди, которые сталкивались с  темой "одномерные методы оптимизации".

Comment: @Adrug я в преф не играл никогда, но их выражение "канделябрами бить" слышал. Скриншот от какой программы Вы привели? Ну да ладно. Заметил расхождение (1.13061e-19 vs 2.77556e-17) при N=90. Поменял все описания double на long double и log10 на log10l. Результат стал 1.13061e-19 vs 1.21973e-19. Дальше с погрешностями разбирайтесь сами.

И, кстати, из сонсольного (cmd.exe) окна лучше делать copy с последующим paste в текст вопроса, чем лепить скриншот.

Comment: Мда, судя по количеству минусующих про методы оптимизации здесь мало кто слышал. 

Так вот, очевидно что иррациональное число фи комп точно посчитать не может, считает он его с некоторой погрешностью. И эта погрешность накладывает ограничения на точность самого метода, читай в любой методичке по численным методам, например тут: http://www.machinelearning.ru/

Ну и вообще по логике вещей: у тебя порядок длины отрезка который ты хочешь получить -17, а выражения с помощью которых ты этот отрезок ищещь считаются с точностью скажем -10. Ничего странного не видишь?

Comment: @Megavolt, методы оптимизации и проблемы погрешности к минусам за ответ отношения (IMHO) не имеют.

В правилах ХК объясняется, что если ответ нравится, то +, а если нет - то -.

Видимо такой ответ не понравился, может его надо было как комментарий написать?

Comment: Хз как вам,но здесь http://orenstudent.ru/GoldCutting.htm более доступно описан данный метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж вопрос всплыл в очереди проверки:

Точность long double - [около 15-17 десятичных цифр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/191860/177221). Это означает, что при работе с числами, близкими к 1, вычислителная погрешность будет порядка 10<sup>-17</sup>, что и наблюдается в этом примере. Точность 10<sup>-24</sup> требует замены double на что-нибудь более точное.

Comment: Для меня этот вопрос уже не актуален, думаю вы правы. Спасибо что помогли!