# Цикл for и счетчик типа double

Tags: java

Почему неверно отображается значение самого счетчика и уходит точность во время выполнения?

```
public class DoubleFor {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (double d = 0.1; d <= 1; d += 0.1 ){

        System.out.println("d = " + d);
    }
}
```

}

компиляция:

> d = 0.1
>   d = 0.2
>   d = 0.30000000000000004
>   d = 0.4
>   d = 0.5
>   d = 0.6
>   d = 0.7
>   d = 0.7999999999999999
>   d = 0.8999999999999999
>   d = 0.9999999999999999
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Полезно для ознакомления: [Вывод числа double (10^18)+1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/191857/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-double-10181/191860#191860)

Comment: Если нужна точность посмотрите на тип `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 3):

Позаимствую объяснение у Ильи Кантора. У него речь про javascript, но всё это применимо к большинству языков программирования без каких либо изменений:

> Число 0.1 (одна десятая) записывается просто в десятичном формате. Но
>   в двоичной системе счисления это бесконечная дробь, так как единица на
>   десять в двоичной системе так просто не делится. Также бесконечной
>   дробью является 0.2 (=2/10).
>
> Двоичное значение бесконечных дробей хранится только до определенного
>   знака, поэтому возникает неточность.
>
> Когда мы складываем 0.1 и 0.2, то две неточности складываются,
>   получаем незначительную, но всё же ошибку в вычислениях.

[https://learn.javascript.ru/number#неточные-вычисления](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Более подробно на английском можно познакомиться по ссылке: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#680

Answer (score 1):

Всё дело в том, что в стандарте IEEE 754 на число выделяется ровно 8 байт(=64 бита), не больше и не меньше.

Для примера число 0.1 (одна десятая) записывается просто в десятичном формате. Но в двоичной системе счисления это бесконечная дробь, так как единица на десять в двоичной системе так просто не делится. Также бесконечной дробью является 0.2 (=2/10).

Двоичное значение бесконечных дробей хранится только до определенного знака, поэтому возникает неточность.

Когда мы складываем например 0.1 и 0.2, то две неточности складываются, получаем незначительную, но всё же ошибку в вычислениях.

В данном же примере тоже самое: конечное значение никогда не будет равно единице.

то же самое происходит в любом другом языке, где используется формат IEEE 754, включая JavaScript, C, PHP, Ruby, Perl.

Взято с [сайта по JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Если уж копируете слово-в-слово, неплохо бы указывать источник.

Comment: @АлексейУколов, справедливо. Добавил. торопился и забыл сначало)