# 64-битный формат IEEE-754 или что-то с числами

Tags: javascript, числа, системы-счисления, ieee-754

Мне непонятна система битов как 64 бита образуют число? 
из [этой статьи](http://learn.javascript.ru/number)

```
alert( 9999999999999999 ); // выведет 10000000000000000
```

"Причина – потеря точности.

Из 64 бит, отведённых на число, сами цифры числа занимают до 52 бит, остальные 11 бит хранят позицию десятичной точки и один бит – знак. Так что если 52 бит не хватает на цифры, то при записи пропадут младшие разряды."

Получается число 1 занимает 64 бита? почему он не становится 2?
Какова вероятность что при работе с числами, что-то подсчитается неправильно? Где можно подробней ознакомиться с этой технологией.

Или облегчите душу тем, что, можно хорошо программировать не зная этого мрако6есия...

Comment: если вам нужна точность, то не используйте формат в котором есть потеря точности. используйте форматы без потери точности. если вы работаете с числами с плавающей запятой, то вы обязательно столкнитесь с потерей точности. пробуйте  сложить 0.1 и 0.2 в консоли браузера.

Comment: `Получается число 1 занимает 64 бита?` Вообще-то **любое** число, представленное в 64-битном формате, занимает 64 бита... другое дело, что оно _может быть представлено_ с использованием меньшего количества битов - но это уже будет ни разу не 64-битный формат...

Comment: @Akina А как предсказать какое число <i>может быть представлено с использованием меньшего количества битов</i>? Например дробные не правильно вычисляются значит там меньшее количество битов?

Comment: @PeGaS мне кажется, программирование это не ваше...

Comment: @Barmaley Вызов принят.

Comment: Для начала тогда потрудитесь объяснить разницу между Java и JavaScript

Comment: К сожалению, нет, это "мракобесие" необходимо знать, т. к. числа в общем случае могут занимать произвольное количество памяти, и если заталкивать их в ячейки фиксированного размера, выйдет "текучая абстракция". Целые числа протекают переполнением, плавающая точка протекает потерей точности при большом числе цифр.

Comment: @PeGaS Всё с точностью до наоборот. Это битность представления определяет, какие значения могут быть в нём представлены, а не значения что-то там определяют.

Comment: Вот это, кажется, ваш случай: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/191860/10105

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, работать с числами больше `9999999999999999` нельзя, и если складывать дробные числа, то использовать `toFixed`:

```
(0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(1) == 0.3
```

Comment: *работать с числами больше 9999999999999999 нельзя* – отчего ж, можно, просто погрешность вычислений и представления будет больше 1, и чем больше число, тем больше (в абсолютном значении) она будет.