# C#. Как преобразовать число с плавающей точкой в аналогичное число, но только с заданным количеством знаков после запятой?

Tags: c#, .net, double

Доброго времени суток!

Возник следующий вопрос: к примеру, у нас есть переменная типа double и некоторая точность (переменная precition), которая будет определять количество интересующих нас знаков после запятой:

```
    double x = 9.3813020199999;
    double precition = 0.001;
```

Зная вышеперечисленные данные, нам нужно получить точное число 9.381 (и без лишних нулей в конце). Есть ли способ это осуществить?

**UPD** Мне необходимо протестировать метод Sqrt (код ниже) и я не знаю, как правильно написать тест для NUnit, если метод возвращает число double. Ведь у нас должно быть expected-значение, которое сравнивается с возвращаемым значением метода.

```
    public static double Sqrt(double x, int n, double precition)
    {
        if (x < 0 && n % 2 == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        double result = x / n;
        double previousResult;
        do
        {
            previousResult = result;
            result = ((double)1 / n) * ((n - 1) * previousResult + (x / Sqr(previousResult, n - 1)));
        }
        while (Math.Abs(result - previousResult) > precition);

        return result;
    }
```

Пока мой тестирующий метод, написанный с помощью NUnit, выглядит так:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class NewtonSqrtTests
    {
        [TestCase(4, 2, 0.001, ExpectedResult = 2.000)]
        [TestCase(27, 3, 0.0001, ExpectedResult = 3.0000)]
        [TestCase(88, 2, 0.001, ExpectedResult = 9.380)]
        [TestCase(81, 2, 0.001, ExpectedResult = 9.000)]
        public double Sqrt_PositiveTest(double x, int n, double precition)
        {
            return NewtonSqrt.Sqrt(x, n, precition);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А вы думаете, что `precition` равно вот именно 0.001? Как бы не так: http://ideone.com/TgKjVj

Comment: Суть не в этом. Это число лишь говорит о том, сколько знаков после запятой мне нужно. Я могу вместо числа 0.001 использовать число 3.

Comment: В этом, в этом. Число 9.381, которое вы хотите получить, точно так же непредставимо в типе `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если говорить о десятичных знаках, то оставаться в рамках типа `double` бессмысленно: в нём вы не можете выразить вашу требуемую точность точно. Например, потому, что в типе `double` **нельзя** точно выразить ни число 0.001, ни число 9.381. ([иллюстрация](http://ideone.com/TgKjVj), [связанный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/191860/10105))

Вам нужно перейти к типу `decimal`, который специально для этого предназначен.

```
double x = 9.3813020199999;
decimal precision = 0.001m;
decimal result = Math.Round((decimal)x / precision) * precision; // 9.381
```

Если количество десятичных знаков известно в виде числа, можно проще:

```
double x = 9.3813020199999;
decimal result = Math.Round((decimal)x, 3); // 9.381
```

---

Обновление: Если оставаться в рамках типа `double`, вы не можете их сравнивать: равенство теоретически одинаковых чисел типа `double`, вычисленных разными путями — практически невероятное событие из-за ошибок округления. В таких случаях используется *примерное равенство с точностью до epsilon*. Например, в NUnit есть для таких целей [специальные функции](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/EqualConstraint#comparing-floating-point-values):

> Values of type float and double are normally compared using a tolerance specified by the `Within` modifier.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Мне в unit-тесте нужно сравнивать expected с actual. Но т.к. метод возвращает double (это необходимое условие задания, я не могу заменить его на decimal), я не могу правильно сравнить expected  с actual. Может быть, у Вас найдутся идеи для решения этой проблемы?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Обновил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, это то, что нужно!)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Кажется, такого [невозможно достичь с `ExpectedResult`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26924319/276994), так что вам придётся немного переписать тесты, передавая ожидаемое значение внутрь.

Comment: да, тут просто нужно будет убрать ExpectedResult, метод сделать void и внутри сделать нужный Assert

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Отлично, хорошо, что проблема решилась!