# Деление числа по разрядам

Tags: c#, строки, float

Доброго времени суток всем! Недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой: необходимо разделить число типа float по разрядам, пример: "1590270,2018" -> "1 590 270,2018". Попытался решить задачу известными мне способами. Вышло нереально много строк кода. И вообще весь код - костыль. Деление по разрядам нужно только для вывода на экран, никакой логической роли это не играет. Язык программирования c#, среда разработка Visual Studio, под WPF. Вроде бы мелочь, а додуматься никак не могу, помогите решить задачу грамотным путём.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве альтернативы, можно использовать [стандартный формат `N`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier):

```
float f = 1590270.2018f;
string s = f.ToString("N3", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

https://ideone.com/lhUMSJ

---

С другой стороны, если приложение запущено на нерусской системе, то логичнее показывать формат в соответствии с настройками системы. Тогда вы можете не указывать `CultureInfo`:

```
string s = f.ToString("N3");
```

и строка будет отформатирована в соответствии с правилами языка, выбранного пользователем. Для русского и французского это будет `12 345 680,000`, для немецкого — `12.345.680,000`, для английского — `12,345,680.000`.

---

Заметьте, что для больших чисел у `float` не хватает точности для показа нужного количества знаков после запятой.

---

Если вам нужно выводить все знаки после запятой, работать через `N` нельзя, т. к. при этом количество знаков после запятой либо нужно указывать вручную (и тогда выведутся нули), либо берётся по умолчанию. В этом случае у меня сработало вот так:

```
string s = f.ToString("#,0.##########", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

или соответственно

```
string s = f.ToString("#,0.##########");
```

Comment: Все бы замечательно но эти способы лишний раз округляют число, например 99 999 999 до 100 000 000.

Comment: @Kasper: На это есть очень простая причина: эти два числа _равны_! Проверка: https://ideone.com/s7MXub

Comment: @Kasper: А вот причина, почему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/191860/10105 (там для `double`, но для `float` то же самое).

Answer (score 2):

Используйте класс NumberFormatInfo:

```
var format = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
format.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
Console.WriteLine(1590270.2018m.ToString("#,0.00", format));
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/vqiqSz)