# Почему при записи большого числа во float меняются цифры на конце?

Tags: c, ieee-754, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Записываю во float myVar число 0xBCA8F85D, если представить это число в десятичном виде в калькуляторе, получаю 3165190237, однако если вывести через printf("%f",a); результат 3165190144, объясните пожалуйста почему так происходит?

Comment: Дубликат: [Вывод числа double (10^18)+1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/191857/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-double-10181)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Стандарт IEEE-754 описывает 32-битное число с точкой, как содержащее 1 бит знака, 8 бит экспоненты и 23 бита мантиссы. В частности, это означает, что точность хранимого числа "всего лишь" около 7 знаков, а разрешенный диапазон, около 10^38.

При записи числа, мантисса дает вам 23 бита на то чтобы записать число (от 1.0 до 2.0), а экспонента дает вам 8 знаков на то чтобы записать степень. При этом экспонента выбирается минимальной (для наибольшей точности по мантиссе). Возьмем простой пример по 2 бита - мантисса от 1 до 2 с шагом 0,25, а экспонента 1/2/4. Как нам записать в такое число `0.19` ? Никак, мы можем записать только максимально приближенное `1,5 ^ -4` и получим `0,197530864197530`. Другой ближайший сосед будет .. (не знаю точно, но допустим) `0,1741254`. И тогда что бы мы не ввели оно будет "округлено" до ближайшего представимого числа в нашем "float5".

Соответственно в вашем случае, полагаться можно только на первые 7 цифр - `3165190***`, а последние три будут "как получится".

Зачем же нужен такой тип, если он даже не может вместить в себя int ? Затем, что в его особенности - его сила. Обычно при работе с числами не так важны мелкие значения на фоне больших. Работаете с миллиардами, не обращаете внимания на единицы. Работаете с миллиметрами - не важны нанометры.

Comment: Это более менее понятно, непонятно, что происходит когда я записываю это 16-ричное число в переменную и почему возникает ошибка в полседних цифрах.