# Double.MIN_VALUE - 1.0D

Tags: java, математика, дискретная-математика

Есть код:

```
System.out.println(Double.MIN_VALUE - 1.0D);
```

Почему его результатом будет `-1.0?`

Comment: А какой результат вы ожидали?

Comment: @AlexeyTen никакой, это был вопрос из кое какого теста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно стандарту IEEE-754 числа с точкой можно записывать в экспоненциальной форме. Этот формат дает боле-менее фиксированную точность (например, для 32бит - около 7 знаков), но в очень широком диапазоне (около +/-10 в 38 степени).

Так вот, `MIN_VALUE` это то минимальное, отличное от нуля, число (без учета знака), которое можно записать в этом формате (для 32бит - около 10^-38).

Соответственно, если вы берете очень малое число (`Double.MIN_VALUE`), и отнимаете от него единицу, то вы получите минус единицу и очень малую часть, которая будет утеряна, т.к. она не попадает в "точность" 7 знаков вокруг единицы.

То есть, грубо говоря у вас получается что-то типа `-1.0000000000000000000000000000123`, которое будет "округлено" и записано как `-1.0000000`.

Дополнительно: [Почему при записи большого числа во float меняются цифры на конце?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803096/)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что [`Double.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE) - это на самом деле не самое маленькое число, которое можно записать в `double`, а значение максимально близкое к нулю. Самое маленькое значение, которое вы можете сохранить в `double` является [`-Double.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE).

Comment: Перечитайте вопрос, "Почему его результатом будет -1.0?" ;-)

Comment: Окей. Просто ответ был бы лучше, если бы он объяснял как это работает (см. нпаример мой ответ), а не брал невысказанное топикстартером предположение и не адресовался только к нему.

Comment: Я вам же подсказываю, как сделать ответ лучше. Не хотите - как хотите )

Comment: Я - я. Лошадь - моя. На недостатки указал. Пример привел. Плюс поставить после внесения правок - готов :-D

Comment: Хм, а давайте ещё объясним до кучи принцип работы компилятора, транслятора. Человек вполне ответил на поставленный вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что в java нет нуля. Это связано с тем, что невозможно представить 2 в такой степени, чтобы был 0. Для решения это проблемы ввели MIN_VALUE. Это наиболее близкое к нулю число (а не минимальное).
Более подробно можете почитать про представление чисел [тут](https://habr.com/post/219595/)

Comment: Скорее потому что банально не хватает точности. Какого, интересно, результата ожидал автор.

Comment: Есть же ноль https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Zero Ну да, специальный, но тем не менее

Comment: В Java есть ноль, что за ересь ))

Comment: Ок, согласен, не совсем верно выразился. Невозможно представить ноль в нормализованной форме.

Comment: Тем не менее, стандарт IEEE754 нам говорит, что если Мантисса и Экспонента нули, то число - 0.

Comment: И тем не менее Вам стоит научиться читать, потому что нули - не нормализованная форма (ну или вы можете найти степень двойки??).