# Почему 6.35.toFixed(1) == 6.3?

Tags: javascript, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Пишет

> Во внутреннем двоичном представлении 6.35 является бесконечной двоичной
>   дробью. Хранится она с потерей точности…

Но я не понимаю почему  `1.35.toFixed(1) == 1.4`
Такая фигня только с 6.35? Почему к примеру 1.35 не является бесконечной двоичною дробью ???

Comment: Связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803096

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Потому что будучи записанной в двоичном представлении, `6.35` будет "округлена" до ближайшего представимого числа (32-битного в этом примере) в формате IEEE-754 - `01000000110010110011001100110011`, что при обратном преобразовании даст нам `6.349999904632568359375`, а `1.35`, соответственно `00111111101011001100110011001101` и `1.35000002384185791015625`

`toFixed(1)` же делает простое округление, `6.349` до `6.3`, а `1.35` до `1.4`

P.S. Вот тут есть онлайн просмотрщик представлений чисел: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html