# Почему String(159712434140109896) возвращает "159712434140109900"?

Tags: javascript, строки

В коде преобразование в строку `String(159712434140109896)` возвращает `"159712434140109900"`. Почему так происходит и как это победить?

Comment: Это во всех браузерах или в конкретном? Видимо теряются последние биты в преобразованиях - и неправильно преобразовует. Для больших чисел - разные браузеры могут по разному себя вести.

Comment: Можно попробовать остаток от деления на 10 проверить, если он содержит 6 - то можно написать ф-цию которая "переведёт вручную"

Comment: Потому что настолько большое значение выходит за пределы точности float-чисел (не больше 15-17 десятичных знаков), и с этим ничего не поделать

Comment: потому что 159712434140109896 не представимо, если ты просто выведешь его, ты точно так же увидишь 159712434140109900

Comment: biggestInt = 9007199254740992; максимальное число

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Вывод числа double (10^18)+1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/191857).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отображение числа 9223372036854775807](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690856/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-9223372036854775807)

Comment: `159712434140109896 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` -> `true`