# Полное число в JS

Tags: javascript

Возможно тупой вопрос.

Допустим есть код:

```js
var summa = 2 + 10000000000000000000000000;
console.log(summa);
```

как вывести его полным числом?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Этот вариант работает до 1е21.

```js
summa = 2 + 100000000000000;
console.log(summa.toLocaleString().replaceAll(',', ''));

summa = 2 + 100000000000000;
console.log(summa.toLocaleString('ru-RU', {
  useGrouping: false
}));
```

Этот работает с 1е21+, но число надо указать строкой либо с `n`

```js
summa = "10000000000000000000000000";
console.log(BigInt(summa).toString());

summa = 2n + 10000000000000000000000000n;
console.log(summa.toString()); // summa тут BigInt
```

Comment: А оно точно не должно вывести `10000000000000000000000002` ?) Напоминаю про BigInt,

Answer (score 0):

Если есть целое число, представленное типом `Number`, и принадлежащее интервалу `(-10**21, 10**21)`, то получить его точное строковое представление можно с помощью метода [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
console.log( (Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER).toFixed() );
console.log( (1e+50).toFixed() );
```

Однако, если целое число не принадлежит интервалу `(-10**21, 10**21)`, то для преобразования в строку метод `toFixed()` воспользуется методом [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString), который такие большие числа записывает в [экспоненциальной записи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). Получившаяся строка может оказаться лишь приближенным представлением исходного значения.

Более надёжный способ заключается в преобразовании значения типа `Number` в значение типа `BigInt` с помощью функции [`BigInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). И уже последующий вывод значения типа `BigInt` с помощью метода [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt/toString). Метод `toSting()` преобразует `BigInt` в строку точно.

```js
console.log( BigInt(Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER).toString() );
console.log( BigInt(1e+50).toString() );
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что тип `Number` — это числа с плавающей точкой формата [`IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point format`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Следовательно, далеко не каждое целочисленное вещественное значение может быть представлено данным типом.

Например, целое число `1e+50` данным типом не представимо.
Ближайшее меньшее число с плавающей точкой — это `99999999999999986860582406952576489172979654066176`.
Ближайшее большее — это `100000000000000007629769841091887003294964970946560`.

Целое число из вопроса `1e+25` также нельзя представить точно типом `Number`.
Ближайшее меньшее — `9999999999999998758486016`.
Ближайшее большее — `10000000000000000905969664`.

Если требуется целочисленная арифметика произвольной точности, то можно воспользоваться упомянутым ранее типом `BigInt`. Он как раз для этого и предназначен.

```js
let val = 
    BigInt(55) + //Создаём BigInt из Number
    BigInt("9876543210987654321098765432109876543210") - //Или строки
            8765432100876543210087654321008765432110n;   //Или числовой литерал с суффиксом n
    
console.log(val.toString());
```

Связанные вопросы:

- [Вывод числа double (10^18)+1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/191857).
- [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453).

---

Есть ещё один метод преобразования в строку, по своей семантике похожий на `toFixed()` — это [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). Алгоритм его работы описан в спецификации [ECMA-402](https://402.ecma-international.org/7.0/). Этот алгоритм при работе с целыми числами, насколько я понял, не ограничен интервалом `(-10**21, 10**21)`. В целом он существенно сложнее, чем алгоритм `toFixed()`. Но некоторые этапы в его работе остались для меня загадкой — не совсем понятно, что имели ввиду авторы спецификации. Поэтому утверждать в какую конкретно строку он преобразует то, или иное значение типа `Number` или `BigInt` не стану.

Эксперименты показывают, что некоторые целочисленные значения как вне интервала `(-10**21, 10**21)`, так и **внутри него** он преобразует в строку с ошибкой. Тестовый код:

```js
let magic   = [18014398509481992.0, 999999999999999868928.0, 1e+50];

for (let num of magic) {
    console.log("toFixed:        " + num.toFixed() );
    console.log("bigIntToString: " + BigInt(num).toString() );
    console.log("toLocaleString: " + num.toLocaleString(undefined, {useGrouping: false}) );
}
```

Вывод, который я получил в Chrome 89 и Firefox 75:

```
toFixed:        18014398509481992
bigIntToString: 18014398509481992
toLocaleString: 18014398509481990

toFixed:        999999999999999868928
bigIntToString: 999999999999999868928
toLocaleString: 999999999999999900000

toFixed:        1e+50
bigIntToString: 100000000000000007629769841091887003294964970946560
toLocaleString: 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Здесь результаты `bigIntToString` — это точные строковые представления чисел с плавающей точкой, хранящихся в массиве `magic`.