# Вычисления с плавающей точкой

Tags: c#, c, вычислительный-эксперимент

Есть в Си Шарп вычисления типа

```
 Double x=1.11
Double y=2.34
Double z=x+y
```

Или др.
Нужно все время думать о точности результата или тип даёт постоянную, семь или восемь знаков после запятой?
Округления делать, думать о предоставлении чисел или просто писать десятичные?

А ошибки операций часто бывают? Компилятор сам может исправить?

Comment: Числа с плавающей точкой хранятся в экспоненциальной форме, т.е. мантисса + двоичный порядок. Соответственно, всякий раз, когда получается результат более высокого порядка, вы теряете в абсолютной точности числа (точность мантиссы при этом всегда фиксирована).

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453), [Вывод числа double (10^18)+1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/191857).

Comment: Но думать надо все время о точности или её гарантирует язык? Можем просто складывать, умножать?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Можем просто ограничиться тем, что результат примерный?

Comment: Смотрите в прилинкованный в синей плашке вверху ответ.

Comment: @user2874493 Если у вас лимиты всего 1 знак до и 2 знака после запятой - float вам будет более чем достаточно, если числа больше и точность после запятой нужна выше - читайте статью: https://habr.com/ru/post/201066/

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите практически точных вычислений, то используйте специальный тип [decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.7), он есть не только в `C#`, но и во многих других языках, потому что программы часто пишут и для банков, например, а никто не хочет, чтобы у него деньги неточно считались, этот тип специально придумали для денежных и прочих точных вычислений. Он работает медленнее, чем `float` и `double`, но зато он способен хранить и обрабатывать числа с минимальной потерей точности.

А вообще воспользуйтесь поиском, тут много раз обсуждались проблемы с неточностью чисел с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Но для обычных, не банков децимал все же или дабл?

Comment: Просто у меня конкретный вопрос, округление. А в децимал не надо про это думать?